# How to bind WPF ContextMenu ItemsSource?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemssource

I'm trying to bind Button's context menu this way:

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Values}"/>
</Button.ContextMenu>
```

(UserControl has Values property).

Why doesn't this work?
However when I put this binding into other control like `<TextBlock Text='{Binding ...}'/>` it works OK.

Another question, how do I debug binding problems in WPF?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the ContextMenu isn't part of the visual or logical tree, so it doesn't inherit `DataContext` in the same way as other controls. It isn't a child of your control.

What you can do is use the `PlacementTarget` property of your ContextMenu to get the parent element that the ContextMenu is attached to and go from there.